# Yakuake not responding after hitting F12

Tags: 14.04, command-line, raspberrypi, guake, yakuake

I'm using Yakuake (it's a drop down terminal emulator) to manage my terminals and work in multiple terminals, switch between them...
First you must launch the application and by clicking on F12 the window disappear and F12 again to appear.... etc.

Now after I've opened 2 sessions for my laptop and 2 session on my Raspberry, I can't for now switch to the window: after F12 nothing appears. If I reboot the laptop it will work fine but I have a lot of work that I don't want to lose.

I have found in the System Monitor that Yakuake is still running but I can't access it. I'm using Ubuntu 14.04.

update : i have installed also Guake and i have use F11 to make it appear/disappear but after a while the window cant' be displayed

Comment: Same issue for me on 16.10.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else having this problem, I did some digging and figured out why yakuake was not working correctly. See [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/yakuake/+bug/248661/comments/2) response by presumably the author of the package.

It seems to me that the configuration panel of yakuake is buggy in some way when it does not change or, perhaps, shouldn't have created in the first place, these system-side keybindings.

Hope this helps!

Edit: I figured I should add that the easiest way I found to fix it was to simply delete the system keybind and then recreate it in the yakuake config.

Answer (score 0):

I assumed it was because the key bindings weren't sticking due to a settings issue.

Not the case, yakuake simply was not set to run on startup. Remedy by setting it to run on startup

For KDE Plasma 5

- System Settings -> Startup and Shutdown -> Autostart -> Add Program